# Number of four-digit numbers with nonzero leading digit in two ways

Tags: combinatorics

We would like to count the number of four-digit numbers such that the leftmost digit is nonzero in which at least two digits are the same.

We want to do this in two ways and compare the results.

**First way : complementary set**

Total number of four-digit numbers such that the leftmost digit is nonzero :

$$9\times 10^3 = 9000 $$

Numbers with pairwaise distint digits :

$$9\times 9 \times 8 \times 7 = 4536$$

So the number of those in which at least two digits are the same is

$$ 9000 - 4536 = 4464$$

**Second way : bruteforce**

number of numbers with all digits identical :

$$ 9$$

number of numbers with three identical digits :

$$4\times 9 \times 8 + 9 $$ (case containing $0$ and the other case)

number of numbers with two identical digits :

$$6\times 9 \times 8 \times 7 + 3 \times 9 \times 8 $$

We we sum this up we get

$$ 3546 $$

I don't see what is my mistake.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: By leading digit is usually meant highest power of 10 like 7 in 7233.

Comment: yes I meant leftmost sorry (edited)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, both of your solutions are wrong.

$9\times9\times8\times7=4536$ so the number of integers where at least two digits are the same is $9000-4536=4464$

Now we know the answer, let's try to enumerate the digits:

number of 4-digit integers with 4 identical digits: $9$

number of 4-digit integers with only 3 identical digits: $9\times4\times8+9+27$

Because we have ${4 \choose 3}$ ways to choose positions of our (non-zero) identical digits, times 9 (non-zero digits), times 8 (remaining non-zero digits).  You forgot to count $27$ additional cases which represent the number of cases where the non-identical digit is $0$ (e.g. $1011$). This can be calculated as $9{4 \choose 3} - 9$ (we subtract 9 for the cases where the integer is of the form $0xxx$)

You could also count all the configurations first (including those that start with $0$) and then subtract $9$ (counted configurations of the form $0xxx$) and then $ 9{3 \choose 2}$ (configurations of the form $0x00$, $00x0$ or $000x$). Again you'd find $10*9*{4 \choose 3} - 9 - 9{3 \choose 2}=324$ such integers

Following this logic, can you count how many 4-digit integers have only 2 identical digits?

Comment: the statement says "where "at least" two digits are the same "

Comment: you're partially right, I was mistaken in my first calculations (i did it by hand)

Comment: @ahmed Yes you're right on the wording, however the answer should be correct (I checked by writing a quick script)

Comment: isn't it 6*9*8*7 + 3*9*8
the first term counts numbers with all digits are non zero and containing two identical digits

the second term counts the case where two zeroes occur

Comment: You're still missing some edge-cases. Where is $1013$ counted?

Comment: I got you thanks

Comment: is the number I missed 3*3*9*8 (3 places for the zero, 3 places for the two identical and ..) ?

Comment: You're almost there! What about two pairs of two digits like 1001?

Answer (score 6):

All four digits the same: $aaaa$
$9$ choices for $a$, total numbers: $1\times 9=9$

Three digits the same: $aaab, aaba, abaa, abbb$
$9$ choices for $a$ and $9$ for $b$, total: $4\times 9\times 9=324$

Two digits the same, other two distinct: $aabc, abac, abca, abbc, abcb, abcc$
$9$ choices for $a$, $9$ for $b$ and $8$ for $c$, total: $6\times 9\times 9\times 8=3888$

Two digits the same, other two also same: $aabb, abab, abba$
$9$ choices for $a$ and $9$ for $b$, total: $3\times 9\times 9=243$

Grand total: $9+324+3888+243=4464$